# I am getting this error on jenkins integration with protractor using gulpfile.js

Tags: jenkins, automation, gulp, protractor, continuous-integration

This is the exception I am getting on my Jenkins build console:

```
[17:30:35] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
[17:30:35] 

[17:30:35]  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:191)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.launch(GridLauncherV3.java:238)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:99)

[17:30:35] Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
[17:30:35] 
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have another process running on the same port as selenium server.
See [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959471/can-i-run-selenium-server-on-different-ports-at-the-same-time).

Comment: I have checked the port as well.The port is free,But m still getting this error.